# asp.net datalist checkbox get unique selected

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, datalist

I have a datalist control where there are one checkbox in each ItemTamplate. Along with the checkbox there is also a hyperlink to display some documents. Users should be able to click on a checkbox which will display the corresponding document in a Label Control, using StringBuilder. The code below is almost working but it shows duplicates: For example, if I select a checkbox in row 1 and then select another checkbox in row 2 then the Label control will display the document from row 1 twice and then display the document from row 2 once. Here is the relevant code. Thanks!

```
<tr runat="server" id="tr_data">
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb_docid" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' OnCheckedChanged="displayselectedinit"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_docfileencr" Text='<%# Eval("docfileencr") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDFEncr/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "docfileencr") %>'
                                            Target="_blank" runat="server" />
                                        <br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

protected void displayselected()
{
    //return;
    lbl_currselection.Text = "";
    StringBuilder docselected = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (DataListItem li in DataList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || li.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBox cb = li.FindControl("cb_docid") as CheckBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    HyperLink hpl_docfile = li.FindControl("hpl_docfileencr") as HyperLink;
                    docselected.Append(hpl_docfile.Text + "<br />");
                    lbl_currselection.Text += docselected;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `displayselected` is called from nowhere.

Comment: it is called indirectly: displayselectedinit calls displayselected; the reason I am using displayselected is because it is also being called from another 'Select All' checkbox; Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 docselected.Append(hpl_docfile.Text + "<br />");
 lbl_currselection.Text += docselected;
```

You are appending the stringbuilder, as well as adding the label.

Currently, the code is executing this way:

First loop:

```
Adding: Text1
docselected = Text1<br/>
lbl_currselection = Text1<br/>
```

Second Loop:

```
Adding: Text2
docselected = Text1<br/>Text2<br/>
lbl_currselection = Text1<br/>Text1<br/>Text2<br/>
```

I would move the lbl_currselection.Text to the end (out of the loop) and use:

```
foreach (DataListItem li in DataList1.Items)
{
    if (li.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || li.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        CheckBox cb = li.FindControl("cb_docid") as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                HyperLink hpl_docfile = li.FindControl("hpl_docfileencr") as HyperLink;
                docselected.Append(hpl_docfile.Text + "<br />");                    
            }
        }
    }
}
lbl_currselection.Text = docselected;
```

Comment: Nugent: I think simply moving lbl_currselection.Text = docselected; to the end of the displayselected() is doing the trick; let me confirm it...

Comment: Nugent: Your code is working fine. Dummy me, btw. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
protected void DisplaySelected(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = DataList1.Items.Cast<DataListItem>()
        .Where( li => ((CheckBox)li.FindControl("cb_docid")).Checked)
        .Select(li => ((HyperLink)li.FindControl("hpl_docfileencr")).Text);
    lbl_currselection.Text = String.Join("<br />", selected);
}
```

Comment: Hey Tim: I think I have tried Nugent's and it is working; I think your's will probably work as well. But I want to understand this code in var selected: I have not seen such use of 'where' and 'select' clauses in c#. What is happening in this code? Thanks!

Comment: That's [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). You might want to have a look at the 101 LINQ Samples which are very helpful: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b